# Python, Selenium: Incorrectly Scraped Data

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

The code below hard enters a manufacture's part number, `HL4RPV-50` eventually, I would like to cycle in a list of part numbers and return it's information.

For now, I am testing the code for a few inputs, hard codded. When entering one part, `HL4RPV-50` I get a clean output, with no errors.

When I hard code the part `FSJ4-50B` I get a  error

```py
    import time
    #Need Selenium for interacting with web elements
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    #Need numpy/pandas to interact with large datasets
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    import itertools

    chrome_path = r"C:\Users\James\Documents\Python Scripts\jupyterNoteBooks\ScrapingData\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
    driver.get("https://www.tessco.com/login")

    userName = "FirstName.SurName321123@gmail.com"
    password = "PasswordForThis123"

    #Set a wait, for elements to load into the DOM
    wait10 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    wait20 = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
    wait30 = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

    elem = wait10.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "userID"))) 
    elem.send_keys(userName)

    elem = wait10.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "password"))) 
    elem.send_keys(password)

    #Press the login button
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/account-login/div/div[1]/form/div[6]/div/button").click()

    #Expand the search bar
    searchIcon = wait10.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/header/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[2]/i"))) 
    searchIcon.click()

    searchBar = wait10.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/header/div[3]/input'))) 
    searchBar.click()

    #load in manufacture part number from a collection of components, via an Excel file


    #When I search for HL4RPV-50 I get results returned no problem
    #When I search for FSJ4-50B, the price xpath can't be found
    searchBar.send_keys("HL4RPV-50" + '\n')

    # wait for the products information to be loaded
    products = wait30.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='CoveoResult']")))
    # create a dictionary to store product and price
    productInfo = {}
    # iterate through all products in the search result and add details to dictionary
    for product in products:
        # get product info such as OEM, Description and Part Number
        productDescr = product.find_element_by_xpath(".//a[@class='productName CoveoResultLink hidden-xs']").text
        mfgPart = product.find_element_by_xpath(".//ul[@class='unlisted info']").text.split('\n')[3]
        mfgName = product.find_element_by_tag_name("img").get_attribute("alt")

        # get price
        price = product.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='price']").text.split('\n')[1]
        print(price)

        # add details to dictionary
        productInfo[mfgPart, mfgName, productDescr] = price

    print()
    print()


    for (mfg_part, mfg_OEM, description), price in productInfo.items():
        mfg_id = mfg_part.split(': ')[1]
        if mfg_id == 'HL4RPV-50':
            print('Part #:', mfg_id)
            print('Company:', mfg_OEM)
            print('Description:', description)
            print('Price:', price)

    print()
    print()

    #time.sleep(5)
    driver.close()
```

Output for HL4RP-50 is:

```
$1.89
$1.89
$19.94
$39.26
$32.99
$33.33
$42.82
$20.30


Part #: HL4RPV-50
Company: CommScope
Description: 1/2" Plenum Air Cable, Off White
Price: $1.89
```

Output for FSJ4-50B is:

```
$85.68
$2.78
$115.51

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NoSuchElementException                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-112-92a2ced2ae46> in <module>
     59 
     60     # get price
---> 61     price = product.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='price']").text.split('\n')[1]
     62     print(price)
     63
```

Why am I getting an error when searching for a different part? I checked the XPATH's, and they are the same.

Comment: Are you entering `FSJ4-50B` manually, after your products loop started?

Comment: As I was trying to determine the suggestion you are proposing, I indented the ```for products in products``` loop and was able to return the correct pricing. Though, it did retrun the results twice. I did however get another error messege. This one `NoSuchElementException` for `price = product.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='price']").text.split('\n')[1]`

Comment: As an update, when I indented the `for product in products` line, the output for `HL4RPV-50` prints 8 times, the number of products returned from the search. When entering `FSJ4-50B`, the code prints the correct pricing, but tanks after printing itself 3 times.

Comment: Hope this is the duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57019604/python-selenium-nosuchelementexception-on-generic-xpath). If not let me know, I can take a look into this.

Comment: Yes!! It is, I just logged in to update this as part of the other thread. I was able to track down an issue with the XPATH. I am also thinking the `[1]` is forcing `price` to return the first value it finds, as opposed to the second item in the array.

Comment: That's the reason why I used `[-1]`, so that I will always pick the last item after splitting the price.