# Python: Selenium, NoSuchElementException on generic XPATH

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

I have code which allows me to return all searched parts from a specific website, given a keyword.

When the search term "HL4RPV-50" is used, I can get back all returned values as expected.

When I use the search term "FSJ4-50B", I get a `NoSuchElementException` for the line:

```py
    ---> 53     price = product.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='price']").text.split('\n')[1]
```

The direct XPATH is:

```py
    //*[@id="search"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[6]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/add-product-to-cart/div[1]
```

Which is NOT the same direct XPATH for both part ID's. Furthermore, each part ID has a slightly different XPATH based on the position of the part given it's results.

I was under the impression I can reference a relative XPATH to resolve this issue.

The site I am trying to scrape from is [Tessco.com](https://tessco.com) and a generic UN/PW is specified in the code below.

**Identifying the XPATH ID:**

To make a generic XPATH, I was under the impression to use a `.` to select the current node, and `//` to select nodes in the document from the current node that match the selection no matter where they are.

I then specified its type, here it's `div` and then `@class='price'`

For "HL4RPV-50" this gives me what I want, for "FSJ4-50B" it does not.

I belive I have the wrong XPATH, but unsure of how to generalize it.

Any suggestions?

**The Code:**

```py
    import time
    #Need Selenium for interacting with web elements
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    #Need numpy/pandas to interact with large datasets
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd

    chrome_path = r"C:\Users\James\Documents\Python Scripts\jupyterNoteBooks\ScrapingData\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
    driver.get("https://www.tessco.com/login")

    userName = "FirstName.SurName321123@gmail.com"
    password = "PasswordForThis123"

    #Set a wait, for elements to load into the DOM
    wait10 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    wait20 = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
    wait30 = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

    elem = wait10.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "userID"))) 
    elem.send_keys(userName)

    elem = wait10.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "password"))) 
    elem.send_keys(password)

    #Press the login button
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/account-login/div/div[1]/form/div[6]/div/button").click()

    #Expand the search bar
    searchIcon = wait10.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/header/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[2]/i"))) 
    searchIcon.click()

    searchBar = wait10.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/header/div[3]/input'))) 
    searchBar.click()

    #load in manufacture part number from a collection of components, via an Excel file

    #Enter information into the search bar
    searchBar.send_keys("FSJ4-50B" + '\n')

    # wait for the products information to be loaded
    products = wait30.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='CoveoResult']")))
    # create a dictionary to store product and price
    productInfo = {}
    # iterate through all products in the search result and add details to dictionary
    for product in products:
        # get product name
        productName = product.find_element_by_xpath(".//a[@class='productName CoveoResultLink hidden-xs']").text
        # get price
        price = product.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='price']").text.split('\n')[1]
        # add details to dictionary
        productInfo[productName] = price
    # print products information   
    print(productInfo)

    #time.sleep(5)
    driver.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the working code
I disabled the images because My Internet connection was slow and the website was taking time to load the page. 
I used css selector instead xPath for price and its fully working>

```
import time
#Need Selenium for interacting with web elements
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
#Need numpy/pandas to interact with large datasets
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

chrome_path = r".\web_driver\chromedriver.exe"
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path, chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.tessco.com/login")

userName = "FirstName.SurName321123@gmail.com"
password = "PasswordForThis123"

#Set a wait, for elements to load into the DOM
wait10 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait20 = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait30 = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

elem = wait10.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "userID")))
elem.send_keys(userName)

elem = wait10.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "password")))
elem.send_keys(password)

#Press the login button
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/account-login/div/div[1]/form/div[6]/div/button").click()

#Expand the search bar
# searchIcon = wait10.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "")))
# searchIcon.click()

searchBar = wait10.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#searchBar input")))

#Enter information into the search bar
searchBar.send_keys("FSJ4-50B")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a.inputButton').click()
time.sleep(5)

# wait for the products information to be loaded
products = driver.find_elements_by_xpath( "//div[@class='CoveoResult']")
# create a dictionary to store product and price
productInfo = {}
# iterate through all products in the search result and add details to dictionary
for product in products:
    # get product name
    productName = product.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='productName CoveoResultLink hidden-xs']").text
    # get price
    price = product.find_element_by_css_selector("div.price").text.split('\n')[1]
    # add details to dictionary
    productInfo[productName] = price
# print products information
print(productInfo)
#time.sleep(5)
driver.close()
```

**Output:**

```
{"8' Jumper-FSJ4-50B NM/NM": '$147.55'}
```

**Edited:**

**How to choose selector**

[image]

As you can see in the above screenshot, I hover over the **searchBar** and come to know this have an **ID**, and we know **ID** is always unique element on the webpage so we can also use:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("searchBar")
```

but to reach to the **input** field I prefer **css_selector** and then send keys.

**For finding `a.inputButton` css selector:**

For `a.button` css selector see select the searchButton you will see the following html in the dom:

```
<a class="CoveoSearchButton inputButton button"><span class="coveo-icon">Search</span><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

and we know `<a>` is the anchor tag, and from above html, we can deduce that one of the css_selector can be:

```
a.inputButton
```

***NOTE***

But this is unique here in this case sometimes the same class name can be used multiple time in different elements on the same page,so then you have to use the upper level of nodes to reach the child **CSS element** node. e.g, the `a.inputButton` can also be traversed as:

**another css_selector for searchButton**

```
div.divCoveoSearchbox > a.inputButton
```

as `div` is the parent element to our inputButton's anchor Tag.

**I hope I've clear your point?**

Comment: Thanks! I can now see that the `NoSuchWebElement` exception occured because the code was unable to find the webElement by XPATH. The CSS selector was a better choice for this variable `price` An interesting note to your output is this, the description does not match the price it is showing. Looks like some webElement variables need to be located by XPATH and some by CSS.

Comment: prefer using search by ID or class name where ever possible, XPath is sensitive to the position of an element in source, so can lead to element not found or the wrong element if there is any element not loaded.

Comment: yeah, its another way around. But CSS selector is also a better choice.

Comment: @GigaByte The code works great, but I wanted to learn more of how u identified the CSS. Looking at the elements on the site & trying to find how you were able to identify the CSS. Using Chrome/inspect, I hovered over the elements and went to copy the `selector`. It gave me something that differs from what you had. I saw the `styles` section on the right side of the inspector & can't find how you found `a.inputButton` or `#searchBar input`  I download ChromePlugin, "Copy CSS Selector" and I was able to find `#searchBar input` but not `a.inputButton`. How were you able to identify the CSS value?

Comment: @GigaByte Holy moley, that's super clear. I get it now. Thank you VERY much!!

Answer (score 1):

Some products have different class name `price sale` that why you are getting `NoSuchElementException`. Update the price related line in the loop as below.

```
oPrice = product.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='price' or @class='price sale']").text.split('\n')[-1]
price = oPrice[oPrice.find('$'):]
```

Comment: That's a very good observation! I will modify my code as a second version to test this. Thank you again!